# MySQL Triggers get column name

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

I'm inserting every update or insertion into a log table. And I'm using triggers to perform this.

My question is, is there a way to know which column was updated or inserted information and how to retrieve that column name **not the value ?

For example:

Contact Information changed the phone of the user, so I want to put in Logs the name of the column, not the value changed.

User |  Name  |  Phone

Answer (score 2):

There is no (simple/built-in) way to get the column name's that were updated. You will have to write a check for each column. You could muck around with prepare sql and the information_schema table, but writing checks for each column will be cleaner and faster.

```
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET @Cols = 'Updated Columns: ';

IF OLD.col1 <> NEW.col1 THEN
 @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols, 'col1, ');
END IF;

IF OLD.col2 <> NEW.col2 THEN
 @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols, 'col2, ');
END IF;

.....

END
```

Comment: Nothing specific, I always prefix my variables with @ so I don't get confused between column names and local trigger/procedure variables.